# How can I fit a image read from SQL Server Database into a Datagridview column (C#)

Tags: c#, image, datagridview

I have an employee table with EmployeeID, Name, LastName, Picture, DateofBirth.

I am filling a Datagridview with all the rows in this table. It works fine, but the pictures are bigger (92x92pixels) than the datagridview's cells and in every cell only shows a little bit of the face of each person.

Once the Datagridview is filled I put the following code to try make the pictures smaller and strech them to the size of each cell:

```
foreach (DataGridViewImageColumn column in dataGridView.Columns)
          {
                column.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch;                
          }
```

I understand that this code looks for every column that stores pictures. In my case is only one column. Once it finds a columns makes the pictures in all its rows fit the cells (Stretch). But it does not work. It gives me a runtimer error:

> Additional Information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn' to type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewImageColumn'.

I would indeed appreciate all your comments,

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're getting that error because you are trying to convert every column into a DataGridViewImageColumn in your loop. Instead, just do this for the image column only. (Ex. `this.dataGridView.Columns[3].ImageLayout` or `this.dataGridView.Columns["Picture"].ImageLayout`)

Comment: Hello @OhBeWise, thank you for your answer. I tried it but it didn´t work because when I type `this.dataGridView.Columns["Picture"].` there is no ImageLayout property to set the `DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch` value. Instead I did this:

Comment: `foreach (DataGridViewRow drows in dataListado.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell dcell in drows.Cells)
                {
                    if (dcell.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewImageCell))
                    {
                        ((DataGridViewImageCell)dcell).ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch;                        
                    }
                }
            } `

Comment: I had to check for the type of every cell in the datagridview (instead of checking for the type of every column). When I find a cell that is Image the I Stretch it. So far this is working and it run fast but I do not know if this is the most efficient way to accomplish this. Anyways thank you so much for your answer @OhBeWise

Comment: You might try setting an individual cell to stretch (using your type check) in the [`DataGridView.CellFormatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) event handler. This would remove the need for your nested loops. But definitely test thoroughly for performance to determine which method works best for your individual case.